# How to make a stereoscopic 3D Game with SDL for iOS

Tags: c++, graphics, ios, opengl-es, sdl

I was looking up google for an answer the whole night but didn't find anything. Yesterday I found some VR demos and games on the AppStore, with stereoscopig (dual rendered) screens. So you put your phone into a google cardboard and experience a oculus rift like feeling.
But how is that possible using C++ and SDL?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used SDL or made anything for iOS so I might have missed something, but with that said.

I think your best bet would be to look into OpenGL ES (Embedded System), using [OpenGL with SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guidevideoopengl.html) can be enabled with SDL_SetVideoMode.

Normally you would be able to use [quadbuffering for stereoscopy](http://www.gali-3d.com/archive/articles/StereoOpenGL/StereoscopicOpenGLTutorial.php) in OpenGL, but I [don't think the ES allows for that](https://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/7196-3D-Stereoscopic-with-OpenGL-ES), in that case you need to find details for how to enable it for your device first. A simple method would be to use [anaglyph glasses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D), simply render left and right views and then use fragment shaders to render them both to the viewport with the correct tinting.

For anything else you would have to give more details about what hardware your targeting, hope it helps.